# How to access to the "first" selector of jQuery .on()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying is, having this script:

```
$('[data-foo]').on('click', '.button-action', function() {
    // Show alert on $('.button-action', this).
    // Alert message: Lorem ipsum {$('.foo-id', this).text()}
});
```

And I have multiple elements like this, that are generated dynamically:

```
<div data-foo="{id}>
    <div class="foo-id">
        Lorem Value
    </div>
    <button class="button-action">Click to show the id of this data-foo</button>
</div>
```

In other words, I want to access to `$('[data-foo]')` of `this` button I clicked.

Comment: How are they generated? Could you possibly add an `id` to each button, which would solve this issue cleanly?

Comment: They're generated with a random `data-foo` value and `Lorem Value`, what I'm trying is to have just a general `ID` which in this case is `data-foo` and based on that ID, target the events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`event.delegateTarget`](https://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/) to access the element the handler is attached to (`[data-foo]` in this case):

```
$('[data-foo]').on('click', '.button-action', function(event) {
    console.log($(event.delegateTarget).find('.foo-id').text());
});
```

But if you always want to get `foo-id` and it's always the previous sibling, you can just use `.prev()` as well:

```
console.log($(this).prev().text());
```

Comment: Awesome! This worked perfectly. Thanks, Felix.
And thanks everyone for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `$(this).parent()`:

```
$('[data-foo]').on('click', '.button-action', function() {
  console.log($(this).parent())
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `click` directly on the button, and grab the `data-foo` from there:

```
$('.button-action').on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).closest("div").data('foo'));
});
```

Fiddle: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5edscpkg/2/)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly, you want to get the first ancestor `[data-foo]` element of the clicked button, right? Then this should work:

```
$('[data-foo]').on('click', '.button-action', function(ev) {
  var $dataFoo = $(this).closest('[data-foo]');
  alert($dataFoo[0].nodeName);
});
```